# Ignore html tags when loading page

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a simple php script ignoring html content in a database and not loading it using php?
Like: don't load images, or anchors, or elements with class=""...

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean? For the browser? Or remove something from HTML content before you output it to the browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: @hakre The OP didn't say anything about trying to parse the HTML.

Comment: @MichaelMior: The OP says nothing really specifically. I asked for more info as well, in case it's related to change attribute values of specific PHP tags, a HTML parser comes to play, so I thought this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use function **strip_tag('your content here')**. It will remove all HTML tags from your content and gives pure text base output.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). It removes HTML tags from a text. You can also specify list of tags to keep.

Have to say, parsing text content from a HTML page requires more complex operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

> This function tries to return a string with all NUL bytes, HTML and
>   PHP tags stripped from a given str. It uses the same tag stripping
>   state machine as the fgetss() function.